# Next.jsにて正体不明のエラーが発生しました

Tags: next.js

Next.jsでよくわからないエラーが発生しました

AppRouterのNext.jsにおいて`npm run dev`で開発者サーバーを立ち上げてコンソールに以下のような2つのエラーが出ます

```
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:318:11)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

```
Uncaught Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted
```

<状況>
ある時にこのエラーが出ました
いつ出たかよく覚えていません、ただ不思議なことに過去の、エラーが出ていなかった頃のコミットを読み込んで試してみても、このエラーが出ます。なのでgithubに挙げているようなコード自体に問題があるわけではないようです

<試したこと>
・npmの再インストール
・Next.jsの再インストール
・Next.jsのダウングレード
・別でリモートレポジトリからクローンを作って実験
・別PCで実験
・新しくひな形を作り、内容をコピペして実験

なお、いずれを試しても同じエラーが出ました

<これらを踏まえて>
本当にこのエラーの要因が分かりません
僕の記憶としては、コンポーネント以外いじってないはずなのです。そして過去のコミットを読み込んでも同じような状況になるので困り果てています

非常に少ない情報で申し訳ないのですが、もし少しでも解決案がある方はご協力を頂けると助かります
レポジトリは以下です、これで実際に試せるかと思います↓
https://github.com/sotetu-79/typing-adventure